# QueryDSL Collection contains

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, collections, querydsl

Simple QueryDSL code that searches for users with specific single role.
It was working in the past (version `findByUserRole_1()`) and now I get exception after upgrading to the latest Hibernate.

The question: Is there a way to fix QueryDSL code to work with new Hibernate 6?

**findByUserRole_1()**

```
org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Operand of 'member of' operator must be a plural path
```

**findByUserRole_2()** Alternate `where` clause also throws exception:

```
org.hibernate.query.QueryArgumentException: Argument [ROLE_ADMIN] of type [com.thevegcat.app.config.UserRole] did not match parameter type [java.util.Set (n/a)]
```

**findByUserRole_3()** This one also used to work and now throws exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicAttributeMapping cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.TableGroupJoinProducer (org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicAttributeMapping and org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.TableGroupJoinProducer are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

---

**UserRole.java**

```
public enum UserRole {
    ROLE_ADMIN,
    ROLE_ADVANCED,
    ROLE_EDITOR,
    ROLE_USER,
    ROLE_ANONYMOUS
}
```

---

**User.java**

```
@Entity 
public class User {
    // ...

    @Convert(converter = UserRolesConverter.class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private Set<UserRole> roles;

    // ...
}
```

---

**UserRepositoryImpl.java**

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl 
    // ...

    public List<User> findByUserRole_1( final UserRole userRole ) {
        final QUser user = QUser.user;
        return 
            new JPAQueryFactory(this.entityManager)
                .selectFrom(user)
                .where(
                    new BooleanBuilder().and(user.roles.contains(userRole)).getValue()
                )
                .fetch();
    }

    public List<User> findByUserRole_2( final UserRole userRole ) {
        final QUser user = QUser.user;
        return 
            new JPAQueryFactory(this.entityManager)
                .selectFrom(user)
                .where(
                    new BooleanBuilder().and(user.roles.any().eq(userRole)).getValue()
                )
                .fetch();
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

**UserRepository.java**

```
public interface UserRepository extends
    PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Integer>,
    CrudRepository<User, Integer>
{
    // ...

    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles r WHERE :role IN ( r )")
    List<User> findByUserRole_3(UserRole role);

    // ...
}
```

---

Bug report that I created about this issue:
https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/3618

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, and the info in this article resolved my problem after some contextual tinkering for my project.

https://aregall.tech/hibernate-6-custom-functions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).